# Make forward-word not to jump over newline character

Tags: navigation, words

I have a text like this,

```
testStatus['id'] = elt.$.id^^''&&&&
testStatus$$['suite_id'] = ""
```

where `^^` is my cursor position. When I press `M-f`, it uses `forward-word` and end up in the place `$$` in line number two.

How can I force `M-f` to treat newline characters as a word seperator and just stop at the end of line number one.

This works fine, when the last part of line one has some alphabets.

```
testStatus['id'] = elt.$.id^^''&&&&abcd$$
testStatus['suite_id'] = ""
```

where `^^` is my initial cursor position and `$$` is my new cursor position.

Comment: & is not in a word syntax! When you want Emacs to go to the end of a line why don't you just command it with <kbd>C-C-e</kbd>?

Comment: What not using `forward-sexp` instead of `forward-word`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look before you leap!

You can write a custom function which will look for non word characters followed by a new line before next word. On such condition go to end of line other wise run normal word forward.

```el
(defun my-forward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "\\W+\n")
      (when (search-forward-regexp "\n" nil 'noerror)
        (goto-char (match-beginning 0)))
    (forward-word)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-f") 'my-forward-word)
```

**Update:**

This can be simplified futher using `forward-sexp` as mentioned by @Name

```el
(defun my-forward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "\\W+\n")
      (forward-sexp)
    (forward-word)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-f") 'my-forward-word)
```

Comment: anand, one closing paren at `my-forward-word`'s end is missing

Answer (score 1):

Oh , if you are using evil-mode you can just add this line to your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(setq-default evil-cross-lines nil)
```